# How can I implement PageView in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am new to SwiftUI. I have three views and I want them in a PageView. I want to move each Views by swipe like a pageview and I want the little dots to indicate in which view I'm in.

Comment: Try using `UICollectionView`. Here's a great tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5yjOMLBfSc

Comment: [SwiftUIX](https://github.com/SwiftUIX/) has a SwiftUI wrapper for `UIPageViewController` - see [PaginatedViewsContent.swift](https://github.com/SwiftUIX/SwiftUIX/blob/master/Sources/Intramodular/Paging/PaginatedViewsContent.swift).

Comment: Please check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57028165/swiftui-scrollview-how-to-modify-content-offset-aka-paging/58302447#58302447) . It is pure SwiftUI, so I found the lifecycle easier to manage. Also, you can write any custom SwiftUI code in that.

Comment: For the pager, check out out [this](https://gist.github.com/Gujci/9154323a1eaf555d718120767ce9ce1d)

Answer (score 112, accepted):

### iOS 15+

In iOS 15 a new `TabViewStyle` was introduced: [`CarouselTabViewStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/carouseltabviewstyle?changes=latest_minor) (**watchOS only**).

Also, we can now set styles more easily:

```
.tabViewStyle(.page)
```

### iOS 14+

There is now a native equivalent of `UIPageViewController` in SwiftUI 2 / iOS 14.

To create a paged view, add the `.tabViewStyle` modifier to `TabView` and pass `PageTabViewStyle`.

```
@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            TabView {
                FirstView()
                SecondView()
                ThirdView()
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
        }
    }
}
```

You can also control how the paging dots are displayed:

```
// hide paging dots
.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
```

You can find a more detailed explanation in this link:

- [How to create scrolling pages of content using tabViewStyle()](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-create-scrolling-pages-of-content-using-tabviewstyle)

---

#### Vertical variant

```
TabView {
    Group {
        FirstView()
        SecondView()
        ThirdView()
    }
    .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: -90))
}
.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
.rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 90))
```

---

#### Custom component

If you're tired of passing `tabViewStyle` every time you can create your own `PageView`:

**Note:** TabView selection in iOS 14.0 worked differently and that's why I used two `Binding` properties: `selectionInternal` and `selectionExternal`. As of iOS 14.3 it seems to be working with just one `Binding`. However, you can still access the original code from the revision history.

```
struct PageView<SelectionValue, Content>: View where SelectionValue: Hashable, Content: View {
    @Binding private var selection: SelectionValue
    private let indexDisplayMode: PageTabViewStyle.IndexDisplayMode
    private let indexBackgroundDisplayMode: PageIndexViewStyle.BackgroundDisplayMode
    private let content: () -> Content

    init(
        selection: Binding<SelectionValue>,
        indexDisplayMode: PageTabViewStyle.IndexDisplayMode = .automatic,
        indexBackgroundDisplayMode: PageIndexViewStyle.BackgroundDisplayMode = .automatic,
        @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content
    ) {
        self._selection = selection
        self.indexDisplayMode = indexDisplayMode
        self.indexBackgroundDisplayMode = indexBackgroundDisplayMode
        self.content = content
    }

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
            content()
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: indexDisplayMode))
        .indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: indexBackgroundDisplayMode))
    }
}

extension PageView where SelectionValue == Int {
    init(
        indexDisplayMode: PageTabViewStyle.IndexDisplayMode = .automatic,
        indexBackgroundDisplayMode: PageIndexViewStyle.BackgroundDisplayMode = .automatic,
        @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content
    ) {
        self._selection = .constant(0)
        self.indexDisplayMode = indexDisplayMode
        self.indexBackgroundDisplayMode = indexBackgroundDisplayMode
        self.content = content
    }
}
```

Now you have a default `PageView`:

```
PageView {
    FirstView()
    SecondView()
    ThirdView()
}
```

which can be customised:

```
PageView(indexDisplayMode: .always, indexBackgroundDisplayMode: .always) { ... }
```

or provided with a `selection`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selection = 1

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Selection: \(selection)")
            PageView(selection: $selection, indexBackgroundDisplayMode: .always) {
                ForEach(0 ..< 3, id: \.self) {
                    Text("Page \($0)")
                        .tag($0)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @pawello2222, awesome code! Implements nicely with swifty syntax. As of right now, however, the indicator dots do not update with the selected view when not using a `ForEach` loop. If I manually type out: `MyView(text: message[0]) ... MyView(text: message[n])`; regardless of which view I swipe to, the indicator remains at `index[0]`.

Comment: @JustinBush Unfortunately, the SwiftUI internal implementation can change with every iOS release. TabView selection no longer works in the same way as in iOS 14.0, so I updated my answer with a new implementation.

Comment: Your PageView works - but unfortunately adds up an awful lot of memory when swiping complex Views. Any idea why ? (I'm on iOS 14.4.2)

Comment: There is a big disadvantage in that implementation - it's not lazy like UIpageviewcontroller

Answer (score 33):

Page Control

```
struct PageControl: UIViewRepresentable {
    var numberOfPages: Int
    @Binding var currentPage: Int
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIPageControl {
        let control = UIPageControl()
        control.numberOfPages = numberOfPages
        control.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGray
        control.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.darkGray
        control.addTarget(
            context.coordinator,
            action: #selector(Coordinator.updateCurrentPage(sender:)),
            for: .valueChanged)

        return control
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIPageControl, context: Context) {
        uiView.currentPage = currentPage
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        var control: PageControl

        init(_ control: PageControl) {
            self.control = control
        }
        @objc
        func updateCurrentPage(sender: UIPageControl) {
            control.currentPage = sender.currentPage
        }
    }
}
```

Your page View

```
struct PageView<Page: View>: View {
    var viewControllers: [UIHostingController<Page>]
    @State var currentPage = 0
    init(_ views: [Page]) {
        self.viewControllers = views.map { UIHostingController(rootView: $0) }
    }

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            PageViewController(controllers: viewControllers, currentPage: $currentPage)
            PageControl(numberOfPages: viewControllers.count, currentPage: $currentPage)
        }
    }
}
```

Your page View Controller

```
struct PageViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var controllers: [UIViewController]
    @Binding var currentPage: Int
    @State private var previousPage = 0

    init(controllers: [UIViewController],
         currentPage: Binding<Int>)
    {
        self.controllers = controllers
        self._currentPage = currentPage
        self.previousPage = currentPage.wrappedValue
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIPageViewController {
        let pageViewController = UIPageViewController(
            transitionStyle: .scroll,
            navigationOrientation: .horizontal)
        pageViewController.dataSource = context.coordinator
        pageViewController.delegate = context.coordinator

        return pageViewController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, context: Context) {
        guard !controllers.isEmpty else {
            return
        }
        let direction: UIPageViewController.NavigationDirection = previousPage < currentPage ? .forward : .reverse
        context.coordinator.parent = self
        pageViewController.setViewControllers(
            [controllers[currentPage]], direction: direction, animated: true) { _ in {
            previousPage = currentPage
        }
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {
        var parent: PageViewController

        init(_ pageViewController: PageViewController) {
            self.parent = pageViewController
        }

        func pageViewController(
            _ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
            viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
            guard let index = parent.controllers.firstIndex(of: viewController) else {
                return nil
            }
            if index == 0 {
                return parent.controllers.last
            }
            return parent.controllers[index - 1]
        }

        func pageViewController(
            _ pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
            viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
            guard let index = parent.controllers.firstIndex(of: viewController) else {
                return nil
            }
            if index + 1 == parent.controllers.count {
                return parent.controllers.first
            }
            return parent.controllers[index + 1]
        }

        func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, didFinishAnimating finished: Bool, previousViewControllers: [UIViewController], transitionCompleted completed: Bool) {
            if completed,
                let visibleViewController = pageViewController.viewControllers?.first,
                let index = parent.controllers.firstIndex(of: visibleViewController) {
                parent.currentPage = index
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Let's say you have a view like

```
struct CardView: View {
    var album: Album
    var body: some View {
        URLImage(URL(string: album.albumArtWork)!)
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(3 / 2, contentMode: .fit)
    }
}
```

You can use this component in your main SwiftUI view like this.

```
PageView(vM.Albums.map { CardView(album: $0) }).frame(height: 250)
```

Comment: What does the `vm.Albums` part look like? Is it data that you're passing into the PageView?

Comment: @BrodyHigby 

Yes. its an array of albums

Comment: Awesome stuff! Seems to work great for me on iOS 16 and lets me hook into more things than SwiftUI's `TabView` does. Might be worth knowing you can  do away with the custom `PageControl` if you implement `UIPageViewControllerDataSource`'s `presentationCount` and `presentationIndex` as it'll show its own.

Comment: Note: There's an extra opening brace in the `setViewControllers` trailing closure, in `updateUIViewController` that breaks compilation.

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 5**

To implement a page view in swiftUI, Just we need to use a `TabView` with a page style, I'ts really really easy. I like it

```
struct OnBoarding: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            Page(text:"Page 1")
            Page(text:"Page 2")
        }
        .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .always))
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

Comment: You wrote about Swift 5, but I think its better to mention the OS version like macOS11+ or iOS 14+.

Answer (score 3):

#### iOS 13+ (private API)

*Warning: The following answer uses private SwiftUI methods that aren't publicly visible (you can still access them if you know [where to look](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56530199/8697793)). However, they are not documented properly and may be unstable. Use them at your own risk.*

While browsing SwiftUI files I stumbled upon the `_PagingView` that seems to be available since iOS 13:

```
@available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
public struct _PagingView<Views> : SwiftUI.View where Views : Swift.RandomAccessCollection, Views.Element : SwiftUI.View, Views.Index : Swift.Hashable
```

This view has two initialisers:

```
public init(config: SwiftUI._PagingViewConfig = _PagingViewConfig(), page: SwiftUI.Binding<Views.Index>? = nil, views: Views)
```

```
public init(direction: SwiftUI._PagingViewConfig.Direction, page: SwiftUI.Binding<Views.Index>? = nil, views: Views)
```

What we also have is the `_PagingViewConfig`:

```
@available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
public struct _PagingViewConfig : Swift.Equatable {
  public enum Direction {
    case vertical
    case horizontal
    public static func == (a: SwiftUI._PagingViewConfig.Direction, b: SwiftUI._PagingViewConfig.Direction) -> Swift.Bool
    public var hashValue: Swift.Int {
      get
    }
    public func hash(into hasher: inout Swift.Hasher)
  }
  public var direction: SwiftUI._PagingViewConfig.Direction
  public var size: CoreGraphics.CGFloat?
  public var margin: CoreGraphics.CGFloat
  public var spacing: CoreGraphics.CGFloat
  public var constrainedDeceleration: Swift.Bool
  public init(direction: SwiftUI._PagingViewConfig.Direction = .horizontal, size: CoreGraphics.CGFloat? = nil, margin: CoreGraphics.CGFloat = 0, spacing: CoreGraphics.CGFloat = 0, constrainedDeceleration: Swift.Bool = true)
  public static func == (a: SwiftUI._PagingViewConfig, b: SwiftUI._PagingViewConfig) -> Swift.Bool
}
```

Now, we can create a simple `_PagingView`:

```
_PagingView(direction: .horizontal, views: [
    AnyView(Color.red),
    AnyView(Text("Hello world")),
    AnyView(Rectangle().frame(width: 100, height: 100))
])
```

Here is another, more customised example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selection = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        _PagingView(
            config: _PagingViewConfig(
                direction: .vertical,
                size: nil,
                margin: 10,
                spacing: 10,
                constrainedDeceleration: false
            ),
            page: $selection,
            views: [
                AnyView(Color.red),
                AnyView(Text("Hello world")),
                AnyView(Rectangle().frame(width: 100, height: 100))
            ]
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Am I right to assume this won't be accepted in an App Store application?

Comment: @iSpain17 TBH I don't really know - never tried it myself. I assume it won't be accepted because it uses private undocumented methods but I'm not 100% sure. This might help you: [How does Apple know you are using private API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2842357/8697793)

Answer (score 2):

For apps that target iOS 14 and later, the answer suggested by @pawello2222 should be considered the correct one. I have tried it in two apps now and it works great, with very little code.

I have wrapped the proposed concept in a struct that can be provided with both views as well as with an item list and a view builder. It can be found [here](https://github.com/danielsaidi/SwiftUIKit/blob/master/Sources/SwiftUIKit/Views/MultiPageView.swift). The code looks like this:

```swift
@available(iOS 14.0, *)
public struct MultiPageView: View {
    
    public init<PageType: View>(
        pages: [PageType],
        indexDisplayMode: PageTabViewStyle.IndexDisplayMode = .automatic,
        currentPageIndex: Binding<Int>) {
        self.pages = pages.map { AnyView($0) }
        self.indexDisplayMode = indexDisplayMode
        self.currentPageIndex = currentPageIndex
    }
    
    public init<Model, ViewType: View>(
        items: [Model],
        indexDisplayMode: PageTabViewStyle.IndexDisplayMode = .automatic,
        currentPageIndex: Binding<Int>,
        pageBuilder: (Model) -> ViewType) {
        self.pages = items.map { AnyView(pageBuilder($0)) }
        self.indexDisplayMode = indexDisplayMode
        self.currentPageIndex = currentPageIndex
    }
    
    private let pages: [AnyView]
    private let indexDisplayMode: PageTabViewStyle.IndexDisplayMode
    private var currentPageIndex: Binding<Int>
    
    public var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: currentPageIndex) {
            ForEach(Array(pages.enumerated()), id: \.offset) {
                $0.element.tag($0.offset)
            }
        }
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: indexDisplayMode))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*first you adds the package* ***https://github.com/xmartlabs/PagerTabStripView***
then

```
import SwiftUI
import PagerTabStripView

struct MyPagerView: View {

    var body: some View {
   
        PagerTabStripView() {
            FirstView()
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
                .pagerTabItem {
                    TitleNavBarItem(title: "ACCOUNT", systomIcon: "character.bubble.fill")
                       
                }
            ContentView()
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
                .pagerTabItem {
                    TitleNavBarItem(title: "PROFILE", systomIcon: "person.circle.fill")
                }
         
              NewsAPIView()
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
                    .pagerTabItem {
                        TitleNavBarItem(title: "PASSWORD", systomIcon: "lock.fill")
                    }   
        }   
        .pagerTabStripViewStyle(.barButton(indicatorBarHeight: 4, indicatorBarColor: .black, tabItemSpacing: 0, tabItemHeight: 90))
          
 }
   
}

struct TitleNavBarItem: View {
    let title: String
   let systomIcon: String
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: systomIcon)
             .foregroundColor( .white)
             .font(.title)
    
             Text( title)
                .font(.system(size: 22))
                .bold()
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color.orange)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to do this is via [iPages](https://github.com/benjaminsage/iPages).

```
import SwiftUI
import iPages

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var currentPage = 0
    var body: some View {
        iPages(currentPage: $currentPage) {
            Text("")
            Color.pink
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is Open source, but isn't FREE.