# How to show page indicator for LazyHGrid in Swift UI

Tags: swift, swiftui, grid, lazyhgrid

I want to achieve the pagination and page indicator with dots as in Swift (UIPageControl) in swift UI.
I am using a lazy H grid, and a button inside a for Each loop to get the horizontal grid. How to add the page indicator to LazyHgrid to achieve this design?  [image]

Comment: Could [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63348858/swiftui-how-to-implement-paging-on-user-swipe-previously-used-uicollectionvie) be the solution?