# Loop TabView | SwiftUI | iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, ios14

I have a ForEach loop inside a TabView.

```
struct PageView: View {
    var imageViewModels: [ImageViewModel]
    var height: CGFloat
    var body: some View {
        
        TabView {
            ForEach(imageViewModels) { viewModel in
                Image(viewModel.name)
            }
        }
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: height)
        .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
        
    }
}
```

My question: Is there a way to loop the images inside the tab view?
Ex: If the user swipes right on the first image he goes to the last one. If he swipes left on the last image he goes to the first one.

Comment: It looks like you need UIPageViewController for this. See this answer: [How can I implement PageView in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58396319/8697793)

Comment: Thank you for your comment @pawello2222 . But the PageTabViewStyle does exactly the same thing as a UIPageViewController as far as I'm aware. My problem is that I can't put it in a loop like a carousel. Do you think I'd be able to do that with a UIPageViewController?

Comment: UIPageViewController allows for much more customisation. In the linked example see how the `func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController)` function (for changing the next tab) is overriden.

Comment: And especially the part: `if index + 1 == parent.controllers.count { return parent.controllers.first }`