# SwiftUI - How to add selection to TabView

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, tabbar, xcode12

I have a JSON API, and I want to show the content inside the PageTabView. It is successful, but  the view becomes laggy every time I swipe the page and I got the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66591530/15132219. But the problem is now the page dots doesn't want to change every time I swipe the page. I have tried to solve it for days but still can't find the solution, Here is my Code (I can't show the API link as it's not shareable)

```
struct HomeBanner: View{
    @State var banners: [BannerJSON] = []
    private let timer = Timer.publish(every: 5, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    @State var index = 0
    var body: some View{
        
        let bannerPic = "API_LINK"
        
        GeometryReader{ geometry in
            VStack(spacing: 2){
                if banners.isEmpty{
                    Spacer()
                    ProgressView()
                    Spacer()
                }else{
                    VStack{
                        ZStack{
                            TabView(selection: $index){
                                ForEach(banners, id: \.id){banner in
                                    VStack{
                                        //MARK: Display Banner
                                        NavigationLink(destination: DetailBanner(banner: banner
                                        )){
                                            WebImage(url: URL(string: bannerPic + banner.IMAGE))
                                                .resizable()
                                                .scaledToFit()
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height / 3.5)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.onAppear{
                getBannerData(url: "API_LINK"){
                    (banners) in
                    self.banners = banners
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct BannerJSON{
    var RECORD_STATUS: String
    var IMAGE: String
    var URL_LINK: String
    var TITLE: String
    var DESCRIPTION: String
}

extension BannerJSON: Identifiable, Decodable{
    var id: String {return TITLE}
}
```

Comment: Please make mock data if you can't include the API link. https://www.mockaroo.com

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll provide a mock data next time ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct SampleTabView: View {
    @State var selectedIndex: Int = 0
    @State var banners: [Int] = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selectedIndex){
            ForEach(0..<banners.count, id: \.self){ idx in
                Text(banners[idx].description)
                    .tag(idx)//This line is crutial for selection to work put in on the VStack
                    //You can also make the tag the banner in your loop but your selection variable must be a Banner too. 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: However, I can't use the NavigationLink anymore since I am using idx that is Integer (Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'BannerJSON'). Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Use the code banners[idx] just like the Text View

Comment: Thanks!! now it is work perfectly as I expected!