# Pageview Image Gallery in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, image-gallery, icarousel, pageviews

I'm just trying to learn SwiftUI as my background is in UIKit. How to implement a pageview mechanism with 3 images per page? Like in the photo below, current page is showing 3 images. Since there's 3 dots, it means that the number of images are 7-9. This should be dynamic, which means that when I got 14 images, I should be showing 5 dots.

I should be able to swipe to left and load the next set of images. The last set might contain 1-3 images.

I'm using SwiftUI 1.0 as I need to support iOS 13.

[image]

Comment: Create a TabView, set the style to PageTabViewStyle() and add 3 images per tab.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I implement PageView in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58388071/how-can-i-implement-pageview-in-swiftui)

Comment: @nicksarno, is TabView available in iOS 13? Also, can it handle dynamic content?

Comment: @pawello2222 I think I already saw the link you provided. Unfortunately, it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: In iOS 13 you can use `UIViewRepresentable` as proposed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58396319/8697793