# Error creating a custom PageView in SwiftUI 2

Tags: swiftui, pageviews

I am working on an app that requires 6 items in a `PageView`, `xcode` was acting up so i came on Stack Overflow and found pawello2222's way, found it really helpful but I still need to connect it to the horizontal links on top. here is the code, thanks a million.

Original solution: [How can I implement PageView in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58388071/how-can-i-implement-pageview-in-swiftui/63159912)

Below is my code and what I want to achieve, swiping left or right works, but clicking on the links does not change the view

```
struct TestingView: View {
    @State var selection = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack(spacing: 10) {
                VStack {
                    Text("Link 1")
                        .foregroundColor(self.selection == 0 ? Color.blue : Color("Silver").opacity(0.7))
                        .font(.caption)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .clipShape(Rectangle())
                        .onTapGesture {
                            withAnimation(.default) {
                                self.selection = 0
                            }
                        }
                }

                Spacer(minLength: 0)

                VStack {
                    Text("Link 2")
                        .foregroundColor(self.selection == 1 ? Color.blue : Color("Silver").opacity(0.7))
                        .font(.caption)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .clipShape(Rectangle())
                        .onTapGesture {
                            withAnimation(.default) {
                                self.selection = 1
                            }
                        }
                }

                Spacer(minLength: 0)

                VStack {
                    Text("Link 3")
                        .foregroundColor(self.selection == 2 ? Color.blue : Color("Silver").opacity(0.7))
                        .font(.caption)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .clipShape(Rectangle())
                        .onTapGesture {
                            withAnimation(.default) {
                                self.selection = 2
                            }
                        }
                }
            }

            PageView(selection: $selection, indexDisplayMode: .never, indexBackgroundDisplayMode: .never) {
                VStack {
                    FirstView()
                }
                .tag(0)

                VStack {
                    SecondView()
                }
                .tag(1)

                VStack {
                    ThirdView()
                }
                .tag(2)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying out ways connecting his code with .onTapGesture {

                    withAnimation(.default){

                        self.selection = 1
                    }
                }

Comment: @pawello2222 Howdy, please your help is needed, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the info. In the original code I used two `Binding` properties due to a TabView bug. It seems that it's fixed now, so I updated my answer - please try it again.

Comment: Howdy @pawello2222 thanks for the reply, i followed and took out one binding as you did, but when i ran the app it built in the simulator alright but crashed when i opened the page with the code, Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffeea0abff8)

Comment: I found the problem, you mistakenly removed the peroid (.)  before tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: indexDisplayMode)) and i followed blindly. haha. thanks so much i really appreciate your help